# Seqsplit fail in mathmode

Tags: seqsplit

I see from the documentation that seqsplit is supposed to work in mathmode.

However, I have the following:

```
Since we know $1000! = \seqsplit{4.0238726007709377354370243392300398571937486421...105933983835777939410970027753472e^{2567}}$, we can represen...
```

And get this error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \futurelet 
l.487 ...15933983835777939410970027753472e^{2567}}
                                                  $, we can represen...
? [ENTER]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.487 ...15933983835777939410970027753472e^{2567}}
                                                  , we can represent...
? [ENTER]
```

It's not clear to me which part of this is underspecified in { or }.  Is it fighting with the e^{}, thinking these are closing seqsplit?

What's strange is the output is correct, but I still have to answer the prompts.

Comment: `\seqsplit` can break sequences of characters; just place `e^{...}` outside it.

Comment: you would get essentially the same error if you did `{1} {2} {^} {2567}` which is more or less what you are asking seqsplit to turn your input into.

Comment: irrelevant but notice that $4.12..e2567$ or $4.12..E2567$ or $4.12...\cdot 10^{2567}$, or etc... are all better than $4.12... e^{2567}$ which is mathematically unsound notation as it raises confusion about whether $e$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: Thanks, jfbu, I actually noticed that too after posting and that was my true solution, switching to capital E and no power, but left the question up to understand the mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\longnumber}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \int_step_inline:nnn { `0 } { `9 }
   {
    \char_set_active_eq:nc { ##1 } { __mittenchops_activenumber_##1: }
    \mathcode##1="8000\scan_stop:
   }
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `. } \__mittenchops_activeperiod:
  \mathcode`.="8000\scan_stop:
  #1
  \group_end:
 }
\int_step_inline:nnn { `0 } { `9 }
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { __mittenchops_activenumber_#1: }
   {
    \mathchar#1\scan_stop:
    \mspace{0mu plus 2mu}
    \penalty0\scan_stop:
   }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__mittenchops_activeperiod:
 {
  \unpenalty
  \mathchar`.\scan_stop:
  \mspace{0mu plus 2mu}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Since we know $1000! = \longnumber{4.023872600770937735437024339230
0398571937486421\dots105933983835777939410970027753472e^{2567}}$, 
we can represent...

\end{document}
```

Each digit is turned into a macro that typesets the digit followed by a glob of zero glue, but stretchable up to 2mu, and by a penalty that allows a line break. The period, however, removes the penalty, so there is no allowed break before and after it. There is no problem with the exponent, because penalties there do nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be a pity to hardcode your `1000!` in the LaTeX source.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% provides \mspace

\usepackage{xintfrac}% provides \xintFac, \xintREZ

\makeatletter
\newcommand\IntToSplitableFloat[1]{%
% We assume input will expand to some (long, *positive*) integer
   % first we handle trailing zeros
   % (unfortunately xint does not provide auxiliaries to get the A, B, C
   %  from the \xintREZ output A/B[C])
   \expandafter\ITSF@parseinput
               \romannumeral0\xintrez{#1}%
   % attention that \xintLen expands its argument but treats it as a
   % number to normalize, so it removes leading zeros, and they may
   % occur as we have trimmed the leading digit. So we use \xintLength
   % but some \expandafter are needed.
   \edef\ITSF@nbofnextdigits
       {\expandafter\xintLength\expandafter{\ITSF@nextdigits}}%
   % compute the final exponent
   \edef\ITSF@exponent{\the\numexpr\ITSF@nbofnextdigits+\ITSF@exp}%
   \ITSF@lead.\mspace{0mu plus 2mu}%
   \expandafter\ITSF@loop\ITSF@nextdigits\relax
   \unpenalty\unskip\nobreak\;10^{\ITSF@exponent}%
}

\def\ITSF@parseinput #1#2/#3[#4]{%
% make global definitions to keep possibility to reuse the
% parsed integer afterwards without recomputing it
  \gdef\ITSF@lead{#1}\gdef\ITSF@nextdigits{#2}\gdef\ITSF@exp{#4}%
  % we assume here #3 is 1 with no error checking...
}

\def\ITSF@loop #1{%
  \if#1\relax\else#1\mspace{0mu plus 2mu}\penalty0 \expandafter\ITSF@loop\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Since we know that $1000! = \IntToSplitableFloat{\xintFac{1000}}$, we
feel that much happier.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I deliberately do not use `e^{..}` notation, see my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458603/seqsplit-fail-in-mathmode/458624#comment1153524_458603)

Comment: if required we can also obfuscate the middle digits into dots (but we needed some computation first to get the number of them; we can always get both exponent and leading digits via `\xintFloatFac` with suitable `\xintDigits` float precision, but to get the trailing digits is more difficult without some exact computation of the whole thing).